# pyTelegramBotAPI message handlers can't see photo

Tags: telegram, message-handlers

I need my telegram bot to forward messages from the private chat to the customer care staff group.

I run this code:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.type=='private') 
def forwarder(message): 
 bot.forward_message(group, message.chat.id, message.id)
 bot.send_message(group, '#id'+str(message.chat.id))
```

It works smoothly with text messages, but does nothing with photos.

Even if I remove all previous message handlers, so there is no conflict with them to handle photos, it still keeps doing nothing.

If I use the `get.updates()` method I can check "manually" if the photo has arrived and I find it.

Edit: Even if i just run this code only

```
import telebot 
bot = telebot.TeleBot("MY TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True) 
def trivial(message): 
 print('yes')

bot.polling()
```

I get 'yes' for text messages and absolutely nothing, not even raised exceptions for photos.

Comment: The user Omid N has the answer. And with a simple example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46242244/11002771

Answer (score 3):

If you add `content_types` as a parameter you will receive whatever is specified in the argument (which takes an array of strings). Probably the default value for that parameter is set to `['text']`. Which will only listen for 'text' messages.

To get the results you're looking for

your test code will look like:

```
import telebot 
bot = telebot.TeleBot("MY TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda, message: True, content_types=['photo','text']) 
def trivial(message): 
 print('yes')

bot.polling()
```

And your working code:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda, message: message.chat.type=='private', content_types=['photo','text']) 
def forwarder(message): 
 bot.forward_message(group, message.chat.id, message.id)
 bot.send_message(group, '#id'+str(message.chat.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Telegram Bot API** there is a resource [`/sendphoto`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)
See:
[Sending message in telegram bot with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860889/sending-message-in-telegram-bot-with-images)

Try to find the related method in the *PyTelegramBotApi*.
Or implement the function to send a photo your own (e.g. using *requests* library in Python). Then you can use it in the message-handlers of your bot, to forward images.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is not in the forward_message method because if i run it typing the message ID it does its job even with pics. As i implied in the 'Edit', the problem is apparently that any message_handler completely miss photos in my code